# How to add customer new entity type and customer new field

Tags: magento-1.7, customer

I want to create a new tab name as "Preference" in customer dashboard and also admin side customer edit page.
I successfully created new tab both side(means Admin and frontend).

Can any one suggest me how to create a two new field and display field in "preference tab" for both side and how i can add, edit field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifted from:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961290/adding-attributes-to-customer-entity/5962237#5962237

---

This is the code for a basic `int` attribute with `text` renderer:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$setup->addAttribute('customer', 'your_attribute_code_here', array(
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'int',
    'label'         => 'Some textual description',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
));

$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
 $entityTypeId,
 $attributeSetId,
 $attributeGroupId,
 'your_attribute_code_here',
 '999'  //sort_order
);

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'your_attribute_code_here');
$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'));
$oAttribute->save();

$setup->endSetup();
```

The unusual step for adding attributes is the `setData('used_in_forms')` this seems to be unique to customer attributes.  Without it, the field won't get rendered, certainly not in the adminhtml anyway.  You can see the valid options for this array in the `customer_form_attribute` database table.

In terms of using a `select` with predefined options, this is what you need:

```
$iAttributeId = $installer->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, 'your_attribute_code_here');
$aClasses = array('TV','DVD','Home Theatre','Air Conditioner','Stereo/Hifi','Game Console','Camcorder','VCR','Set Top Box','PVR');
$aOption = array();
$aOption['attribute_id'] = $iAttributeId;

for($iCount=0;$iCount<sizeof($aClasses);$iCount++){
    $aOption['value']['option'.$iCount][0] = $aClasses[$iCount];
}
$setup->addAttributeOption($aOption);
```

And here is a [walk-through](http://subesh.com.np/2010/01/creating-custom-sourced-multiselect-product-attribute/) on using a custom source for your drop-down

Hope this helps,
JD